# PowerShell Text Box Formatting

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to format text that I output to a text box with PowerShell. Currently the text goes:

Running Last Reboot CheckDays:5Hours:4Minutes:3RebootRecommended

I want it to format to:

Running Last Reboot Check

Days: 5 Hours: 4 Minutes: 3

Reboot Recommended

Here is my code:

```
Function global:LastReboot_Run
        {

            $logstring = "Running Last Reboot Check" -split "`n"
            Add-content C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log -value $logstring
            $logs_TextBox.Text += "`n$logstring"

            $os = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem
            $uptime = (Get-Date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))
            $Display = "" + $Uptime.Days + " days, " + $Uptime.Hours + " hours, " + $Uptime.Minutes + " minutes"
            $logs_TextBox.Text += "`n$Display"

            $FiveDaysAgo = (get-date).addDays(-7)
            #if([dateTime]$FiveDaysAgo = (get-date).addDays(-5))
            if ($FiveDaysAgo -eq $true)
            {
                $logs_TextBox.Text += "`nReboot Recommended"

            }
            else
            {
                $logs_TextBox.Text += "`nReboot - Good"
            }

            $logstring = "Date Since Last Reboot = " + $Display
            Add-content C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log -value $logstring
            $logs_TextBox.Text += "`n$logstring"
            $logstring = "Last Reboot Check Finished"
            Add-content C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.Log -value $logstring
            $logs_TextBox.Text += "`n$logstring"
        }

        LastReboot_Run
```

I tried the `n method and the -split "`n" method but none of them seemed to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[System.Environment]::NewLine` to insert a new line in `TextBox.Text`. Your `TextBox` has to have the `Multiline` property set to `$true`.

You can store this in a variable for easier use:

```
$newline = [System.Environment]::NewLine

$logstring = "$newline$newline`Last Reboot Check Finished"
```

I agree it's a bit ugly code-wise, but it does what you want.

backtick-n does not work but I cannot explain why.

FYI, the `-split` operator is used to cut (split) strings in parts.